# useEffect Cleanup Function React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Although I already added the useEffect cleanup functions , I'm not sure which useEffect is not cleaned up inside my code , it keeps telling me to fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

```js
  //Useffect Functions
  useEffect(
    () =>
      navigation.addListener("beforeRemove", (e) => {
        if (isDoneRef.current) {
          // If we don't have unsaved changes, then we don't need to do anything
          return;
        }
        // Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen
        e.preventDefault();

        // Prompt the user before leaving the screen
        Alert.alert(
          "Cant leave current screen",
          "You have to finish all your delivery",
          [{ text: "OK", style: "cancel", onPress: () => {} }]
        );
      }),
    [navigation, isDone]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
    getLocationUpdates();
    return () => {
      removeLocationUpdates();
    };
  }, [removeLocationUpdates]);

  useEffect(() => {
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((timer) => timer + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
      setTimer(0);
    };
  }, []);

  //Location Tracker Functions
  const hasLocationPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      const hasPermission = await hasPermissionIOS();
      return hasPermission;
    }

    if (Platform.OS === "android" && Platform.Version < 23) {
      return true;
    }

    const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    );

    if (hasPermission) {
      return true;
    }

    const status = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    );

    if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      return true;
    }

    if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED) {
      ToastAndroid.show(
        "Location permission denied by user.",
        ToastAndroid.LONG
      );
    } else if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN) {
      ToastAndroid.show(
        "Location permission revoked by user.",
        ToastAndroid.LONG
      );
    }

    return false;
  };

  const getLocation = async () => {
    const hasPermission = await hasLocationPermission();

    if (!hasPermission) {
      return;
    }

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        setStartPosition(position);
      },
      (error) => {
        Alert.alert(`Code ${error.code}`, error.message);
        setStartPosition(null);
        console.log(error);
      },
      {
        accuracy: {
          android: "high",
          ios: "best",
        },
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 15000,
        maximumAge: 10000,
        distanceFilter: 100,
        forceRequestLocation: true,
        forceLocationManager: true,
        showLocationDialog: true,
      }
    );
  };

  const getLocationUpdates = async () => {
    const hasPermission = await hasLocationPermission();

    if (!hasPermission) {
      return;
    }

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      await startForegroundService();
    }

    setTracking(true);

    currentPositionRef.current = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        setCurrentPosition(position);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      {
        accuracy: {
          android: "high",
          ios: "best",
        },
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        distanceFilter: 100,
        interval: 5000,
        fastestInterval: 2000,
        forceRequestLocation: true,
        forceLocationManager: true,
        showLocationDialog: true,
        useSignificantChanges: false,
      }
    );
  };

  const removeLocationUpdates = useCallback(() => {
    if (currentPositionRef.current !== null) {
      stopForegroundService();
      Geolocation.clearWatch(currentPositionRef.current);
      currentPositionRef.current = null;
      startPositionRef.current = null;
      setTracking(false);
    }
  }, [stopForegroundService]);

  const startForegroundService = async () => {
    if (Platform.Version >= 26) {
      await VIForegroundService.createNotificationChannel({
        id: "locationChannel",
        name: "Courier Tracking Location",
        description: "Tracking User Location",
        enableVibration: false,
      });
    }

    return VIForegroundService.startService({
      channelId: "locationChannel",
      id: 420,
      title: appConfig.name,
      text: "Memantau posisi terbaru ",
      text: "Waktu Berlalu : ",
      text: "Jarak Ditempuh : ",
      icon: "ic_launcher",
    });
  };

  const stopForegroundService = useCallback(() => {
    VIForegroundService.stopService().catch((err) => err);
  }, []);

  const showReturnAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Package Rejected ?",
      "Are you sure?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          style: "cancel",
        },
        {
          text: "OK",
          //   onPress: () => navigation.navigate("DeliveryOnProgress"),
        },
      ]
    );
  };
  const showDeliveredAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Package Delivered ?",
      "Are You Sure ?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          style: "cancel",
        },
        {
          text: "Yes",
          onPress: orderFinished,
        },
      ]
    );
  };
  const orderFinished = () => {
    setIsDone(true);
    removeLocationUpdates();
    navigation.navigate("FinishDelivery");
  };
```

**1. Can someone give me some insight about what I did wrong ?**

**2. Is there any way I can know exactly which functions has not been cleaned up yet ?**

Comment: ` getLocation();
    getLocationUpdates() `  are async but you are not await ing for those. Try adding an await infront of those in useEffect.

Comment: navigation.addListener is not unsubscribed

Comment: turns out the problem was on my timer counter , because when i console.log them , even after i move out from the screen they are still running